# Matplotlib - Show only data that are above a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using *Matplotlib* and *Pandas* to plot data.

However, I want to show on the graph only data that are above a certain value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

# Importing the data using Pandas
BE = pd.read_csv("BE-4YRS.csv")
FR = pd.read_csv("FR-4YRS.csv")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(BE["Week"], BE["percent"], alpha=0.7, c="r", s=BE["percent"]*2, label="Belgium")
ax.scatter(FR["Week"], FR["percent"], alpha=0.7, c="b", s=FR["percent"]*2, label="France")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
```

I tried with :

```
for i in BE["percent"]:
    if i > 75:
        print(i)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
78
100
78
76
77
87
```

But I can't manage to get the corresponding date to these values

Comment: Change ``for i in BE_CFT_18to21["percent"]:`` to ``for i in range(len(BE_CFT_18to21["percent"])):`` and the if-condition should also be rewritten to ``if BE_CFT_18to21["percent"][i] > 75:``, then, instead of print, call ``ax.scatter(BE["Week"][i], BE_CFT_18to21["percent"][i])``

Comment: Thank you so much, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
BE_CFT_18to21 = BE_CFT_18to21[BE_CFT_18to21.percent > 75]
```

Comment: Based on the syntax the in OP's question I'd have thought it would be ```BE_CFT_18to21["percent"][BE_CFT_18to21["percent"] > 75]```

Comment: That works as well : 
BE_ABOVE_75 = BE_CFT_18to21[BE_CFT_18to21["percent"] > 75]
print(BE_ABOVE_75["percent"]) > gives me the percentage that are above 75
print(BE_ABOVE_75["week"]) > gives me the dates

Comment: @Adil sure. 
You can use either ```BE_CFT_18to21["percent"]``` or ```BE_CFT_18to21.percent```